# How can to resolve a coreDNS pods with status ContainerCreating - kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab

I hope somebody can help me.

Well, I'm building a server (CentOS) with Gitlab, Gitlab-Runner, docker, and Kubernetes to CI/CD.

GitLab information

```
Version:        14.10.2
Revision:       07d12f3fd11
Directory:      /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails
DB Adapter:     PostgreSQL
DB Version:     12.7
```

Gitlab-Runner

```
Version:      14.10.1
```

Docker

```
Version:           20.10.15
```

Kubernetes

```
# kubectl version --short
Client Version: v1.24.0
Kustomize Version: v4.5.4
Server Version: v1.24.0
```

Weave Addons

```
# weave status
Version: 2.8.1 (failed to check latest version - see logs; next check at 2022/05/07 22:50:26)
Service: router
Protocol: weave 1..2
Name: 06:16:91:13:ce:26(srvppk.com.br)
Encryption: disabled
PeerDiscovery: enabled
Targets: 0
Connections: 0
Peers: 1
TrustedSubnets: none
Service: ipam
Status: ready
Range: 10.32.0.0/12
DefaultSubnet: 10.32.0.0/12
```

I have one problem with coreDNS pod that is always with the status of **ContainerCreating**. So, I tried a few solutions that I found in forums, but none of them worked for me. See below.

```
# kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                               READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   coredns-6d4b75cb6d-fmvwd                           0/1     ContainerCreating   0          144m
kube-system   coredns-6d4b75cb6d-jshz5                           0/1     ContainerCreating   0          144m
kube-system   etcd-srvppk.com.br                                 1/1     Running             10         144m
kube-system   kube-apiserver-srvppk.com.br                       1/1     Running             0          144m
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-srvppk.com.br              1/1     Running             0          144m
kube-system   kube-proxy-hnwfd                                   1/1     Running             0          144m
kube-system   kube-scheduler-srvppk.com.br                       1/1     Running             10         144m
kube-system   weave-net-h6zdk                                    2/2     Running             0          135m
```

Describe first coredns

```
# kubectl describe pod/coredns-6d4b75cb6d-fmvwd -n kube-system
Name:                 coredns-6d4b75cb6d-fmvwd
Namespace:            kube-system
Priority:             2000000000
Priority Class Name:  system-cluster-critical
Node:                 srvppk.com.br/10.0.10.20
Start Time:           Sat, 07 May 2022 12:29:14 -0400
Labels:               k8s-app=kube-dns
                      pod-template-hash=6d4b75cb6d
Annotations:          <none>
Status:               Pending
IP:
IPs:                  <none>
Controlled By:        ReplicaSet/coredns-6d4b75cb6d
Containers:
  coredns:
    Container ID:
    Image:         k8s.gcr.io/coredns/coredns:v1.8.6
    Image ID:
    Ports:         53/UDP, 53/TCP, 9153/TCP
    Host Ports:    0/UDP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Args:
      -conf
      /etc/coredns/Corefile
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ContainerCreating
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      memory:  170Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:        100m
      memory:     70Mi
    Liveness:     http-get http://:8080/health delay=60s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=5
    Readiness:    http-get http://:8181/ready delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /etc/coredns from config-volume (ro)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-gj9pl (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  config-volume:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      coredns
    Optional:  false
  kube-api-access-gj9pl:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              kubernetes.io/os=linux
Tolerations:                 CriticalAddonsOnly op=Exists
                             node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane:NoSchedule
                             node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule
                             node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason                  Age                     From     Message
  ----     ------                  ----                    ----     -------
  Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  2m52s (x565 over 125m)  kubelet  (combined from similar events): Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to setup network for sandbox "28664f04201a02833f7c3f9c19cebe6a3e9ae55849731d7ee643b3ad1825e6ab": failed to find network info for sandbox "28664f04201a02833f7c3f9c19cebe6a3e9ae55849731d7ee643b3ad1825e6ab"
```

**What did I do wrong?**

Comment: I am actually wondering about the same. I have a StatefulSet where each pod needs to connect to all others. But the first pod fails because the others haven't startet yet.